# how can I do if string endswith vowels like (aioeuAIOEU) give it to me true

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("cumleni daxil et:");
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        char [] b= new char [20];
        if (a.endsWith("aioeuAIOEU")) {
            a.getChars(1, 10, b, 0);
            System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: i don't write like that    (a.endsWith("a") || a.endsWith("e") || a.endsWith("o")...........)

Comment: Please edit your question to add a description, a clear question to it so others can help you faster.

Comment: You are checking if your string end with the full "aioeuAIOEU", not any single letter.

Comment: whether you want like string last char is a vowel or not ?? 
if yes then you can do like this 

`String str = "your string";
"AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(str.substring(str.length() - 1)) > 0;`

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression to check that:

```
if (a.matches("^.*[aeiouAEIOU]$"))
```

That will be `true` if the text in `a` ends with any of `aeiouAEIOU`

Comment: Shouldn't regex be `[aeiouAEIOU]$`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the opposite and check if "aeiouyAEIOUY" contains the last letter of your string:

```
if ( "aeiouyAEIOUY".contains(a.substring(s.length()-1, a.length())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres something that might be in line with what you are trying.
Like others have said its easier to find if the last character is one of the vowels by comparing the last character to a fixed set of lower and upper case vowels.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test4 {
    private static final List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a','i','o','e','u','A','E','I','O','U');

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String a = sc.nextLine();
        if (vowels.contains(a.charAt(a.length()-1))){
            System.out.println("Last character is a vowel");
        }
    }
}
```